# Strange sum involving $\zeta (3)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta

$$\sum _{l=0}^{\infty } \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{k+l}}{2 (l+1)^3 \left((k+1)^3+(l+1)^3\right)}=\frac{9 \zeta (3)^2}{32}$$

I would like to prove the proposed equality, but I do not know where to start.

Comment: The original statement was a bit awkward, so I rephrased it slightly.

Comment: Is the factor 2 on the LHS definitely right? If so, then I'm still making some silly mistake!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^3}$, then $A = -3\zeta(3)/4$. The required sum can be written as:
$$
B = \sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m(-1)^n}{n^3(m^3 + n^3)} = \sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m}{m^3}\left(\frac{(-1)^n}{n^3} - \frac{(-1)^{n}}{m^3 + n^3}\right) = A^2 - B,
$$
whence the result.

Comment: A factor of 2 seems to have gone astray somewhere - probably my mistake - I'll double check.